# Issue on bibliography - non italic publisher after using Polyglossia

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing, polyglossia, italic

I am using Polyglossia as

```
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\englishfont{Computer Modern} %{Latin Modern Roman}
\setotherlanguage{sanskrit}
\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari] {Adobe Devanagari}
```

to have my contents with both English and Devanagari script like

```
english text here \begin{otherlanguage}{sanskrit} जाम \end{otherlanguage} more english text
```

But my problem is in bibliography page where Journal/Conference name is non-italic. I want to have it in italics as Harvard style.
Can someone help me?

PS: As soon as I remove Polyglossia part, bibliography looks all okay with italic journal name.